# Blank Desktop on Lubuntu 14.04 - But works with guest account

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

Lubuntu 14.04 is giving me a blank desktop on log-in. But the guest user works fine.

I read some previous posts and tried the install gnome thing - it gives me more options on the log-in screen but all are still blank.

A reply to a previous question suggested right click might still work - it didn't in my normal set-up but on switching to Openbox it did so I was able to open file manager and am currently backing up data in case I need to do a re-install.

Any suggestions gratefully received (although having been able to access files I've stopped panicking and maybe a reinstall would be best)

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a complete black, as it was in my case. Try pressing the "connect to projector" button(s) on your keyboard. 
Your system may have been switch to projector only mode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try some other desktop environments:

```
Alt+Ctrl+F1
```

Then login then

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Reboot and change the environment at login screen.